# how to get all record from Right table using right out join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm generating Monthly Attendance report sheet where i am able to get records of those employees you marked there attendance on certain day. here the problem that i'm facing is i need each employee listed in the report whether his record exists in attendance table or not.

i have used right outer join but id didn't worked for me, i have look around to other solution but no one solve my problem

```
Declare @fkSerial   [numeric]=0;
Declare @attDateTime [datetime]='2019-04-01';
Declare @Company nvarchar(50)='ZCG';
Declare @Department nvarchar(50)=null;
Declare @StartOfMonth Datetime
Declare @EndOfMonth Datetime
declare @month int
declare @year int
declare @day int
set @month =DATEPART(month, @attDateTime)
set @year =DATEPART(year, @attDateTime)
set @day =DATEPART(day, @attDateTime)
set @StartOfMonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
set @EndOfMonth =  dateadd(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH,0,GETDATE())+1,0));
With DATERANGE  as(
SELECT DT =DATEADD(DD,0,@StartOfMonth)  
       WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1,@StartOfMonth) <=@EndOfMonth 
       UNION ALL  
       SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
       FROM DATERANGE  
       WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <=@EndOfMonth 

)

SELECT fkSerial,company,serial, 
 name,department,attINOUT,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]
FROM 
(SELECT Day(attDateTime) as d1,fkSerial,attDateTime, tblEmployInfo.company,  tblEmployInfo.serial, tblAttendance.attINOUT,
 tblEmployInfo.name,tblEmployInfo.department
FROM tblAttendance RIGHT outer JOIN
    tblEmployInfo ON tblAttendance.fkSerial = tblEmployInfo.serial
where(     
(tblAttendance.fkSerial = @fkSerial  OR @fkSerial  = 0) AND 
(tblEmployInfo.department = @Department OR @Department is null) And 
(tblAttendance.attDate in (select * from DATERANGE)) and 
(tblEmployInfo.company= @Company or  @Company is null)
and tblAttendance.attINOUT=0
)
group by  tblAttendance.attDateTime,tblAttendance.fkSerial,tblEmployInfo.company,tblEmployInfo.serial,tblAttendance.attINOUT,tblEmployInfo.name,tblEmployInfo.department
having tblAttendance.attDateTime= min(tblAttendance.attDateTime)

) p
PIVOT(
MAx(p.attDateTime)
FOR d1 IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30] ) ) AS pvt
ORDER BY 
pvt.fkSerial
```

i need each employee listed in the report whether his record exists in attendance table or not

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your WHERE condition. You have specified tblAttendance.attINOUT = 0 and tblAttendance is your left table, which will be true only when there are records in the left table. So, it will destroy the purpose of your RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Try, replacing tblAttendance.attINOUT = 0 by ISNULL(tblAttendance.attINOUT, 1) = 0 and see whether you get the desired results. Hope this helps you :).

Comment: It could also be the case, that the condition `tblAttendance.attINOUT=0` should be moved from the WHERE-clause to the ON-clause of the join... Then it will only join `tblAttendance` records where `attINOUT` has the value 0...

Comment: Actually, if you put that condition in ON clause, it will not filter out the rows, but will produce NULLs in the left table attributes wherever the condition is not true, since it is an outer join not an inner join. So, having the condition on WHERE clause but converting NULLs as 1 to not match to 0 makes more sense to me.

Comment: You are correct about that. But I was just pointing out that it _might_ be a _possible_ solution. It depends on what the OP actually wants, of course. I must confess that I did not analyze the OP's question thoroughly, so perhaps my remark is not applicable. I apologize if that's the case. But the OP _did_ say that _each_ employee should be listed... I'm not sure if that's always the case when you filter records in the WHERE clause...

Comment: As you said, it is upto the OP to decide what he wants :). Good discussion though.

Comment: @BartHofland i have update my Stored procedure now it is return data as expected, but when i execute the sp from C# it generate exception which is not clear **Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'.**

Comment: if the stored procedure runs well in SQL server, then there is no issue with that. There should some issue with sp call you are making in C#. So, please post the C# call and then we will be in a position to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the join direction, all condition over the secondary table fields (tblAttendance in this case) must be in the join (`ON` Clause), not in the where. Only the intersection's records will match with the equal conditions, and the result will be the same than an `INNER JOIN`. Adding the `OR IS NULL` condition will not be always accurate if there are Nullable fields.

```
SELECT Day(attDateTime) as d1,fkSerial,attDateTime, tblEmployInfo.company,  tblEmployInfo.serial, tblAttendance.attINOUT,
 tblEmployInfo.name,tblEmployInfo.department
FROM tblAttendance 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblEmployInfo 
    ON tblAttendance.fkSerial = tblEmployInfo.serial
    AND (     
        (tblAttendance.fkSerial = @fkSerial  OR @fkSerial  = 0) AND     
        (tblAttendance.attDate in (select * from DATERANGE)) AND
        tblAttendance.attINOUT=0
    )
WHERE
    (tblEmployInfo.department = @Department OR @Department is null) 
    AND (tblEmployInfo.company= @Company or  @Company is null)
```

Also, I would change the order  of the tables and use LEFT JOIN instead, I think is more standard, but this is opt to you

```
SELECT Day(attDateTime) as d1,fkSerial,attDateTime, tblEmployInfo.company,  tblEmployInfo.serial, tblAttendance.attINOUT,
     tblEmployInfo.name,tblEmployInfo.department
    FROM tblEmployInfo 
    LEFT JOIN tblAttendance  
        ON tblAttendance.fkSerial = tblEmployInfo.serial
        AND (     
            (tblAttendance.fkSerial = @fkSerial  OR @fkSerial  = 0) AND     
            (tblAttendance.attDate in (select * from DATERANGE)) AND
            tblAttendance.attINOUT=0
        )
    WHERE
        (tblEmployInfo.department = @Department OR @Department is null) 
        AND (tblEmployInfo.company= @Company or  @Company is null)
```